# jQuery Slider - How to have different times for each image?

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I am trying to get each image to have a different amount of time shown and thought I could use the cycle plugin but cant seem to get it to work, here all the code

jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.slideshow ').cycle({ 
       fx:     'fade', 
       speed:  'fast',
       timeoutFn: function () { 
           return parseInt($(".slideshow img").attr('data-duration')) ;
       }   
     }); 
  });
```

HTML

```
   <div class="slideshow">
    <img data-duration="5400" src="beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img data-duration="50" src="beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img data-duration="50" src="beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img data-duration="50" src="beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img data-duration="50" src="beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
 </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help :)
Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `$(".slideshow img")` matches all five images, and [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will always return the `data-duration` of the first one.

You'll need to use the arguments passed to [timeoutFn()](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) instead:

```
timeoutFn: function(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    return parseInt($(opts.elements[opts.currSlide]).attr("data-duration"))
        * 1000;
}
```

Note that the return value of `timeoutFn()` is expressed in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: @Liam, indeed, it appears that the first argument passed to `timeoutFn()` is the *index* of the animated element and not the element itself. My updated answer fixes the problem.

Comment: still cant get it to work it just freezes on the second slide :( updated- http://liammann.com/testingtest

Comment: @Liam, that's quite a strange plugin you're using... The first argument passed to `timeoutFn()` is sometimes a number, sometimes an element. I ended up ignoring it and using `opts.currSlide` instead. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `timeoutFn` callback is passed several arguments: current slide, next slide, options, and a forward flag. You can update your `timeoutFn` function to look at the current slide:

```
timeoutFn: function(curr, next, options, forward) {
    return parseInt($(curr).attr('data-duration'));
}
```

Reference: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Answer (score 1):

Referrer to the attributes of the current slide element works better:

```
     $('.slideshow ').cycle({ 
       fx:     'fade', 
       speed:  'fast',
       timeoutFn: function (currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) { 
           return parseInt($(currSlideElement).attr('data-duration'));
       }   
     });
```